# KEY_DOWN not working in CURSES

Tags: curses

I'm building a curses module and using KEY_DOWN to check if a arrow down key is pressed.

But, I get a Name error saying KEY_DOWN is not defined.

```
if value == KEY_DOWN:
```

NameError: global name 'KEY_DOWN' is not defined

Comment: You should add more context into this question. What programming language, etc. The syntax looks like Python, but you didn't tag with Python so people may not have noticed your question

Answer (score 3):

Good day!

You have to do:

```
if value == curses.KEY_DOWN:
```

for it to work.

Hope this works!!!
But if this doesn't work show us your code (so we can analyze it)

Comment: You noticed that the question was asked more than 3 years ago right?

Comment: I guess I answered just for fun :P

Answer (score 2):

To follow up to mvndaai's answer, if you want to detect arrow keys in Python, you have to AND together the three different ASCII values.  For example:

```
    key = getch()
    if key == (27 and 91 and 65):   #27 is ESC, 91 is [, and 65 is A
        print("Up key pressed!")
    if key == (27 and 91 and 66):
        print("Down key pressed!")
    if key == (27 and 91 and 67):
        print("Right key pressed!")
    if key == (27 and 91 and 68):
        print("Left key pressed!")
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why the yave a gloabl named KEY_DOWN, but if you want a key down, you need to do 3 getchs. Warning, the first getch is the same as an <kbd>ESC</kbd>. That means you either make sure it doesn't close on <kbd>ESC</kbd> or do a work around like I did below. I also included a chart of what you will get as a getch for each key.

<kbd><kbd>Key
<kbd>ESC</kbd>
<kbd>UP</kbd>
<kbd>DOWN</kbd>
<kbd>RIGHT</kbd>
<kbd>LEFT</kbd></kbd>
<kbd>getch
<kbd>27</kbd>
<kbd>27</kbd>
<kbd>27</kbd>
<kbd>27</kbd>
<kbd>27</kbd></kbd>
<kbd>getch
 
<kbd>[</kbd>
<kbd>[</kbd>
<kbd>[</kbd>
<kbd>[</kbd></kbd>
<kbd>getch
 
<kbd>A</kbd>
<kbd>B</kbd>
<kbd>C</kbd>
<kbd>D</kbd></kbd></kbd>

Which means that when you hit any <kbd>Arrow</kbd> key and you are triggering a <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

In ruby I tried a work around of checking for 27, then doing a quick timeout on another getch. If that gets a [ it is an arrow or something else, otherwise it is the escape key. Here is my ruby code:

```
def read_key
  ch = getch
  return check_escape_chars if ch == 27
  ch
end

def check_escape_chars
  require 'timeout'
  begin
    Timeout.timeout(0.0001) {getch}
    case getch
    when "A"; return "UP"
    when "B"; return "DOWN"
    when "C"; return "RIGHT"
    when "D"; return "LEFT"
    end
  rescue Timeout::Error
    return "ESC"
  end
end
```

Comment: The curses library handles this for you. you just have to use curses.KEY_DOWN

Comment: From my experience, it seems that in Python 3, when using a pad instead of a normal window, this advice and the advice of John Shahbazian is relevant.